# Is it recommended to send JSON handlers through ASP code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, handler, code-behind

This might be off topic and sure is a discussion and not a question that should have one direct answer.

I've been recently working a lot with ASHX files and I love how any source can make posts and receive an answer in one format. I've been using JSON too, if it matters.

Now I'm wondering, what if I'm making an ASP.NET website where each page has it's own code behind access and can do queries on its own, is it still recommended to use a handler?

In other words, is it safe? I will definitely not use AJAX unless the information does not require protection, seeing everyone can look at the post info through the browser's development tools; So communicating with the handler through the code behind sounds right.

My point is - would it be less safe to send posts to a handler, seeing another post is made in the process?

Comment: It wouldn't be any less safe...if you're using AJAX, you're sending the clients data back to the server. The client should already know what data is being sent back, so worrying about people seeing it in the dev tools is kind of pointless. All of your validation and hidden things should take place on the server-side anyways. If you're worried about security from someone looking at the dev tools, then there may be some more issues at play :)

Comment: @tymeJV Point is, they can make their own posts and I am talking about times when the data is meant to be private. For example, if your AJAX post provides dictionary values then you have no worries about people adjusting the posts; But if the data concerns user private data, then things become unsafe.